# Verwendung von Konjunktiv II und Futur II (usage) sowie Wortreihenfolge (word order)

Tags: subjunctive

> Heute ist Mittwoch. Ich bin heute gegangen. Am Freitag werde ich zweimal gegangen sein, aber nur wenn ich auch am Donnerstag gegangen sein würde.
>
> *Today is Wednesday. I went today. On Friday I will have gone twice, but only if I will have also gone Thursday.*

... nur wenn ich auch am Donnerstag gegangen wäre.

*... only if I have also gone Thursday.*

... nur wenn ich auch am Donnerstag ginge.

*... only if I also go Thursday.*

Are any incorrect? Are the word orders correct. Which is preferred, if any, or is something else preferred?

Hinweis: Ich wollte offen lassen, ob ich am Donnerstag gehen werde oder nicht

Answer (score 3):

Das *nur* würde ich vorziehen.

> Heute ist Mittwoch. Ich bin heute gegangen. Am Freitag werde ich nur
>   dann zweimal gegangen sein, wenn ich auch am Donnerstag gehe.

Die Kombination *nur zweimal* würde man auch verwenden, wenn man *selten* ausdrücken wollte - *nur zweimal, nicht fünf Mal*. Deswegen würde ich zur Verdeutlichung noch ein *dann* einschieben, welches aber nicht zwingend ist.

Geht *ginge*?

> Heute ist Mittwoch. Ich bin heute gegangen. Am Freitag werde ich nur
>   dann zweimal gegangen sein, wenn ich auch am Donnerstag ginge.

Das *ginge* drückt aus, dass man nicht vorhat zu gehen - vielleicht weil man vereiteln will, am Freitag zweimal gegangen zu sein. *Gehe* dagegen lässt offen, ob man gehen wird oder nicht.

Man kann den letzten Satz auch umstellen und die Bedingung vorziehen, vor die Konsequenz.

> Heute ist Mittwoch. Ich bin heute gegangen. Wenn ich auch am
>   Donnerstag gehe, werde ich am Freitag zweimal gegangen sein.

Das ist eine einfachere Struktur. Ob man eine solche bevorzugt, hängt vom Kontext und den Absichten ab.

Eventuell will man das *nur* retten:

> Heute ist Mittwoch. Ich bin heute gegangen. Nur wenn ich auch am
>   Donnerstag gehe, werde ich am Freitag zweimal gegangen sein.

Der Kontext ist nicht ganz leicht zu erraten - vielleicht geht es um Wege zur Arbeit (deswegen Deadline Freitag), die man manchmal zu Fuß und sonst per Bus zurücklegt, vielleicht aus Fitnessgründen, und man hat sich ein Ziel von zwei Mal pro Woche gesetzt und der Freitag selbst ist ausgeschlossen aus Gründen, die schon bekannt sind.

Comment: Ja, ich wollte offen lässen, ob ich am Donnerstag gehen werde oder nicht.

Comment: Die Variante mit „ginge” halte ich für falsch.

Comment: @CarstenS: Auch wenn der nächste Satz lautet: "Aber am Donnerstag muss ich fahren, da ich ein schweres Paket dabeihaben werde."?

Comment: Die Variante mit "ginge" ist richtig (für Fälle, in denen das Gehen am Donnerstag als irreal gedacht wird), aber sie klingt unvertraut, weil nicht mehr viele Leute diese Form des Konjunktivs beherrschen und praktisch einsetzen. Der gemeine Mann (von der gemeinen Frau weiß ich's nicht so genau) sagt heute (einfach aber unschön): "wenn ich auch am Donnerstag gehen würde". Jedoch sagt eine alte Stil-Regel: "Wenn-Sätze sind würdelos!" (Letzteres ist normativ gemeint, nicht deskriptiv.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann, nein, das Problem ist nicht, dass viele nicht Dein tolles Bildungsbürgerdeutsch sprechen, sondern dass der Hauptsatz im Indikativ ist.

Comment: @CarstenS So isses - Die Folge aus einem Konjunktiv (irrealis) muss zwingend auch Konjunktiv sein (oder beides Indikativ) - "Wenn ich gehen würde **bin** ich dort" ist Unsinn.

Comment: Das ist aber nicht eine Frage der Grammatik, sondern eher der Logik.

Comment: @tofro 
Auf Englisch ist es richtig Grammatik und Logik zu sagen,
"If he wants to go, he will go."
was streng übersetzt ist,
"Wenn er gehen wollte, wird er gehen."
Er "will gehen" oder nicht, aber wann er "gehen will", "wird" er bestimmt um einem späteren Zeitpunkt "gehen". Also "gehen wollte" ist der Konjunktiv (das Konditional in englisch Sprache, was ist der Konjunktiv II in deutscher Sprache, nicht wahr?), und "wird gehen" ist der Indikativ.

Comment: @Byron Der Satz würde logisch und grammatisch richtig übersetzt lauten: "Wenn er gehen wollte, ginge er" oder "... würde er gehen" - Beide Satzbestandteile im Konjunktiv. "Wenn er gehen wollte, wird er gehen" ist leider im Deutschen auch unlogisch.

Comment: @tofro Man kann sagen,
"Wenn er gehen wollte, würde er gehen."
was streng übersetzt ist,
"If he wants to go, he would go."
Das hat eine etwas andere Bedeutung auf Englisch, da "would go" auf Englisch kann durch die heutige Zeit fortsetzen und ist nicht unbedingt ein einziges Ereignis um einem späteren Zeitpunkt.
Wenn der Konjunktiv II nicht mit dem Indikativ in deutscher Sprache wie in englischer Sprache verwendet werden kann, wie geht es dann auf Deutsch?